# How do I list all stored scripts on an Elasticsearch cluster?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-painless

I would like to be able to list all of the scripts stored on a given Elasticsearch cluster.

The elasticsearch documentation has [clear examples](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.3/modules-scripting-using.html#_request_examples) for how to create, retrieve, use and delete a script with a particular name. Unfortunately, there is no mention of a list endpoint.

The following do **not** work (at least in Elasticsearch 5.4.1):

- <strike>`GET _cat/scripts`</strike>
- <strike>`GET _scripts`</strike>
- <strike>`GET _scripts/`</strike>

Answer (score 34, accepted):

as the metadata output could be huge, use the `filter_path` to display the scripts only:

```
GET _cluster/state/metadata?pretty&filter_path=**.stored_scripts
```

Comment: Nice! I had been filtering all on the client side, but it's always great to trim that response on the server if possible.

Comment: curl version: `curl -X GET "localhost:9200/_cluster/state/metadata?pretty&filter_path=**.stored_scripts"`

Answer (score 2):

[Per the Elastic forums](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/how-do-i-list-all-stored-scripts-get--scripts-doesnt-work/83055/2), this content is embedded in the response to `GET _cluster/state/metadata`